# Oracle SQL – counter for consecutive equivalent values under specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to create a counter column for an SQL query, **which will start with 1 and increase with each consecutive row with consecutive equivalent values, under a specific column, without re-ordering the query output**.

For example, for an SQL query which returns that dummy output:
[image]

I would like to "add" an extra column (C), which will be populated with a "new" counter for every encountered value in column A — starting with 1 and going upwards — without re-ordering the query output:
[image]

**If it helps, I can easily add a running "row id" in the inner SQL - so there's a column that will represent the "correct" order of things.**
I've tried to use `row_number()` for that but it seems to re-order the data.

Comment: Rows in your table don't have any inherent order - so you would need some way, such as another column you haven't shown like a sequential number or timestamp, to determine the correct ordering - otherwise you will get inconsistent results.

Comment: @AlexPoole I can add a row number in the internal query, if it helps.

Comment: It would - as long as it's a sequential number in the order you want the results to appear. That's essentially what I've done in the innermost query in my answer - but mine is based on `order by null` as there is nothing else available to me, which is... dodgy.

Comment: "...without re-ordering the query output..." -- There is not ordering in the rows, so it's not possible to order or to re-order them. Please add some extra column(s) to sort the rows. Otherwise, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AlexPoole adding a row number which represent the desired order via `order by null` is absolutely sufficient. Thank you.

Comment: @TheImpaler an extra row number column - mentioned by AlexPoole - will do the trick just fine :) Unfortunately that's just the data I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an order-by clause you're at the whim of the optimiser and how it chooses to return the unordered data - which can vary over time, or even between runs of the same query.

With your sample data and the db<>fiddle version and set-up and a fair wind, you *can* do this with a variation on [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html):

```
select a, b,
  row_number() over (partition by a, a_grp order by rn1) as c
from (
  select a, b, rn1, rn1 - row_number() over (partition by a order by rn1) as a_grp
  from (
    select a, b,
      row_number() over (order by null) as rn1
    from your_table
  )
)
order by rn1
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data1 | 33 | 1 |
| Data1 | 42 | 2 |
| Data1 | 13 | 3 |
| Data33 | 56 | 1 |
| Data33 | 311 | 2 |
| Data1 | 54 | 1 |
| Data2 | 123 | 1 |
| Data1 | 555 | 1 |

The supposed ordering is captured by the `rn1` alias in the innermost subquery - but again, this isn't guaranteed to give you the same order you get now from a simple select with no ordering. That is then used as part of the calculation and ordering in the outer queries.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4c3a010d8970901b9f1ac381a5acf28d) showing the intermediate steps.

If you have a more robust way to generate that innermost `rn1` value - maybe something you can extract within the existing query that you're trying to add this column to - then it would be more robust, and you could probably then remove a level of subquery.

You could also then probably use `match_recognize` as an alternative, or other gaps-and-islands techniques.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's just a great solution.